# Python - Import module which need to import other module

Tags: python, import, module

I made a module that makes a linear regression model and draws a graph.
So the module needs to import some packages such as sklearn and matplotlib.
And I want to import this module to another python file and use it.

I think either of the two python files needs to import the above packages..
which of them needs to import?

In below case, my_module.py should import LinearRegression? or my_module2.py should?

ex)

```
my_module.py
---------------------------

**from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression**?

class myclass:  
   def a (self):  
   lr = LinearRegression()


my_module2.py
------------------------------
**from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression**?

from my_module import myclass  

i = myclass()  
i.a()
```

Comment: Any direct dependencies should be imported in all modules. If the module you're importing depends on some other modules, it should import them. If your main script _also_ depends on those modules, it should import them.

Comment: So you are saying, In my example, if my_module2.py doesn't have code which uses LinearRegression module, my_module2 doesn't need to import LinearRegression?

Comment: I'm saying you shouldn't use something that you don't import directly, and you shouldn't import things you don't need. Why would you import `LinearRegression` in `my_module2.py`?

Answer (score 0):

First you import it in `my_module.py`, then import * from `my_module.py` to `my_module2.py`.

```
my_module.py
---------------------------
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

class myclass:  
   def a (self):  
       lr = LinearRegression()


my_module2.py
------------------------------
from my_module import *

i = myclass()  
i.a()
```

Comment: "then import *"—why `import *`? That's a bad habit to get into.